# Как использовать свойство объекта в качестве значения для props (теряется реактивность)?

Tags: vue.js

Имеются 2 компонента: список и элемент списка.

См. код ниже.
Проблема в следующем:
В качестве значения одного из входных параметров (isEdit), я пытаюсь использовать значение свойства объекта (editState)
Но когда я меняю значение свойства, значение соответствущего props не меняется.
Т.е. реактивность в этом случает не работает?
Как бы реализовать задуманное?

Список:

```
<template>
  <div class="edit-tag-list">
    <h3>Список тегов</h3>
    <EditTagItem
      v-for="(tagName, key) in tagsAsArray" :key="key"
      :name="tagName"
      :isEdit="editState[tagName]"
      @startEditingTagName="startEditingTagName"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import EditTagItem from './EditTagItem.vue';

export default {
  name: 'EditTagList',
  components: { EditTagItem },
  data: () => ({
    editState: {},
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('tags', ['tagsAsArray']),
  },
  methods: {
    startEditingTagName(tagName) {
        this.editState[tagName] = true;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.tagsAsArray.forEach((item) => {
      this.editState[item] = false;
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Элемент списка (лишнее убрано):

```js
<template>
  <div class="edit-tag-item d-flex clearfix">
    <template v-if="isEdit">
      <input class="mr-auto"/>
      <b-icon class="edit-tag-icon edit-tag-icon-edit" icon="check2-square" variant="success"b-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <span class="edit-tag-name mr-auto">{{ name }}</span>
        <b-icon class="edit-tag-icon edit-tag-icon-edit" icon="pencil-square" variant="primary" @onClick="editTagName"></b-icon>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'EditTagItem',
  components: {
    clickableWrapper,
  },
  props: {
    name: String,
    isEdit: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    editTagName() {
      this.$emit('startEditingTagName', this.name);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны использовать вью сет для реактивности обьектов, подробнее https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2